# Setting up equatable for PFObject

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject, equatable

I m getting error when setting up equatable in swift

```
extension PFObject : Equatable {}

public func ==(lhs:PFObject,rhs:PFObject) -> Bool {

return lhs.objectId == rhs.objectId
}
```

Below the following error I m getting

> Redundant conformance of 'PFObject' to protocol 'Equatable'

Is there any solution for this error?

Answer (score 3):

A change in Swift 2 makes every `NSObject` conform to `Equatable` through the `isEqual` implementation which simply compares pointer values ([read more here](http://mgrebenets.github.io/swift/2015/06/21/equatable-nsobject-with-swift-2/)).

You can use the following extension to override the default implementation of `isEqual`:

```
extension PFObject {
  public override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if (object as? PFObject)?.objectId == self.objectId {
      return true
    } else {
      return super.isEqual(object)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to also compare the types since I believe `objectId` is not necessarily unique across different subclasses of `PFObject`.

Answer (score 0):

`PFObject` inherits from `NSObject` so it is already conforming to `Equatable`.

Instead of adding `Equatable` to a class that already implements it, you should subclass it and override the default implementation.

Comment: @Vimlan.G I added an answer with the implementation that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example implementation of `isEqual` that also checks the object is of the same Parse object type.

```
extension PFObject {
    open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let parseObject = object as? PFObject {
            return parseObject.parseClassName == self.parseClassName && parseObject.objectId == self.objectId
        } else {
            return super.isEqual(object)
        }
    }
}
```